# Android SDK v6 Level 8 API icon

Tags: android, sdk, icons

When I compile my app with Level 8 API and SDK 6, my app icon cannot not be found and the default android icon is shown instead. However, once I use level 4 API, i can see my icon on the screen. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Where are you placing your icon?